# Why can't I split a string on control characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, split, special-characters

I am trying to split a line when I find the characters `^C` or `^B` together. For some reason it is not splitting properly.

I have been on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and tested this and supposedly it should split it.

The lines that I am reading in and trying to split look something like this:

```
SOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE^BSOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE
```

The code is:

```
final_array = []
temp_array = []

array__with_all_of_the_data.each do |x|
  temp_array = x.split(/\^C/)
  temp_array.each do |y|
    final_array << y.split(/\^B/)
  end  
  @final_array << final_array.join(",")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split using the regular expression `/\^[BC]/`:

```
>> 'SOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE^BSOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE'.split(/\^[BC]/)
=> ["SOME_KEY", "SOME_VALUE", "SOME_KEY", "SOME_VALUE"]
```

If you want replace `\B` / `\C` with `,`, use gsub instead of `split` + `join`:

```
>> 'SOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE^BSOME_KEY^CSOME_VALUE'.gsub(/\^[BC]/, ',')
=> "SOME_KEY,SOME_VALUE,SOME_KEY,SOME_VALUE"
```

Comment: That simplifies it a ton!